# CMD: Echo'ing into a new .bat not working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timeout, echo, ping

I have a .cmd file which creates a .bat file that, when called, provides a 500 millisecond delay via `ping`. The code I have for this is:

```
@echo off && SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
("
  echo @echo off
  echo ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 500
  echo exit /b
")>C:\...\timeout.bat
pause>NUL
ENDLOCAL
```

However, the only output into the timeout.bat is

```
@echo off
exit /b
```

Anyone know why it isn't recognising the `ping` command? Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: What does `C:\...\timeout.bat` do? I never saw 3 dots in a path actually. Is it a typo? I replaced it with a simple `timeout.bat` on my side. Executing the code you posted didn't even create a file. It gave me a `0 was unexpected at this time.` error. Removing the double quotes did the job for me. Still I get confused with the `...` what does it do?

Comment: The `C:\...\` is just a placeholder. I have the actual full path on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens If you change your script to this, which is not intended to alter your original intent?

```bat
@Echo Off
(Echo=@Echo Off
  Echo=Ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 -w 500
  Echo=Exit/B)>"C:\NotSecretDir\time_out.bat"
Timeout -1 1>Nul
```

I would suggest that the calling of a batch file which then calls the ping command and returns to the originating process will effectively take longer than the intended half second. For that reason I would suggest you don't bother and just use `@Timeout 1 1>Nul`.

Comment: This was what I had yesterday, with a simple line of `Timeout 2 >Nul /Nobreak` whenever I needed it. However as of this morning, the code now returns errors of `not recognizes as an internal or external command, operatable program or batch file`, and I was forced to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Update: I restarted my computer and now @timeout is functioning again. Still no idea on what caused the error. Just another reason the creator of .bat needs to be hit in the head...

Comment: Update again: @timeout stopped functioning again, however this time no error message is displayed. Even in a blank .bat file, no `Waiting for X seconds` appears. Pressing any key does not advance the file, and I have yet to see the timeout actually finish. It just stays blank.

Comment: Advice, as timeout is a command don't name your batch file timeout.bat or timeout.cmd and the same could be said for pause.bat or any other standard command name. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file will not write any lines to timeout.bat, as your syntax is wrong.

The `("` will produce an error and the rest of your batch will not be executed.